# Show alert only on specific days

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm want an alert to pop up only on some specfic days but don't seem to get through

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wenesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

    d = new Date(); //This returns Wed Apr 02 2014 17:28:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
    x = d.getDay(); //This returns a number, starting with 0 for Sunday

    if ($days = 'Monday,Tuedsay') {
        alert($days[x]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Simple way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wenesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

d = new Date(); //This returns Wed Apr 02 2014 17:28:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
x = d.getDay(); //This returns a number, starting with 0 for Sunday

if ($days[x] = ['Monday,Tuedsay']) {
    alert($days[x]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wenesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

    d = new Date(); //This returns Wed Apr 02 2014 17:28:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
    x = d.getDay(); //This returns a number, starting with 0 for Sunday

    if ($days[x] == 'Monday' || $days[x] == "Tuesday") {
        alert($days[x]);
    }
});
```